# Load Data Before Adding ViewControllers to UITabBarController

Tags: ios, segue, preloading, uitabcontroller

In my application, once the user logs in from the `LoginViewController`, he is directed to the `ProfileTabBarController`.

`ProfileTabBarController` is a subclass of `UITabBarController`.It consists of three view controllers all of which need a reference to an instance of Profile.

When the `ProfileTabBarController` is pushed, it loads the user's profile. Once the profile loads successfully, it sets a reference to profile on each of its view controllers and then adds them as tab items.

The reason I chose this approach is that if the user launches the application and his token hasn't expired, the application should go directly to the `ProfileTabController`; the user need not login again. Rather than duplicate the code for loading the profile in both `AppDelegate` and `LoginViewController`, I felt it was better to encapsulate it in `ProfileTabBarController`.

The problem with this approach is that during the segue, the `UITabBarController` appears black as no view controller has been set. I managed to remedy this by creating a `LoadingViewController` and setting it initially as the only `UIViewController` of `ProfileTabController`

My question is whether there is a better approach to solving this problem. I don't really like the idea of having a `UIViewController` with no other purpose then to display a loading icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to eliminate the Loading ViewController by making use of `NSNotificationCenter`.

- `ProfileTabBarController` adds the three ViewControllers and then begins loading the profile.

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

```
    self.setupUI()
    self.setupViewControllers()
    self.loadProfile()
```

}

- Once loading completes, the `ProfileTabBarController` emits a `ProfileDidLoad` notification.

let completion = { (profile: Profile?) in

```
MBProgressHUD.hideHUDForView(self.view, animated: true)

if let profile = profile {

    self.profile = profile
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(Notification.ProfileDidLoad, object: self.profile)

} else {

    UIAlertView(
        title: "",
        message: NSLocalizedString("Error loading profile", comment: ""),
        delegate: nil,
        cancelButtonTitle: "OK"
        ).show()

}
```

}

- The ViewControllers observe the `ProfileDidLoad` notification:

  func setupNotificationObserver(){

  ```
      NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "profileDidLoad:", name: Notification.ProfileDidLoad, object: nil)

  }

  @objc func profileDidLoad(notification: NSNotification){

      if let profile = notification.object as? Profile{
          self.profile = profile
      }

  }
  ```

In this way, the view controllers are immediately displayed after login without the need of a loading screen.

Answer (score 1):

Presenting a tab view controller with no views doesn't make much sense, so I think your solution of giving it a view controller to handle this loading state makes perfect sense. Throw in some cool animation to keep the user entertained.

It's also possible that something could go wrong and the profile may not load properly. This transitional view controller seems like a good place to put the code to deal with possible errors.